# Angular 2 bootstrap

Tags: angular

Consider the classic first simple example with Angular 2.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module'; 
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

My question is ***how the root Module knows where to search as to find the selector app-root***? Does it go to `index.html` by default or somewhere is defined where to go? If instead of index.html we had index1.html the app should not work.Why?

Answer (score 0):

Searching the selector in `index.html` is default behaviour of Angular as roughly mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#bootstrap-in-maints).

If the project runs with Angular CLI you can modify the file with the `index` entry in the `.angular-cli.json`.

Answer (score 0):

> Simple answer how it kicks off

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ]
```

The `angular-cli.json` file provide the app configuration to the Angular.

> Long answer how it piece together

The selector represent the component of its entirety. in this case `app-root` will load the `./app.component.html`, `./app.component` and `./app.component.css` (if you have) to the browser DOM to be used. So if you had following components

> HomeComponent
>
> UserComponent

They each has the above files with their respective names. If you add the `<app-user></app-user>` in the `HomeComponent` `HTML` file (like in your `index.html` above). It will load the `UserComponent` in that place.

> how the root Module knows where to search as to find the selector app-root?

The answer for this is the `app.module.ts`; you must tell the `AppModule` where to find the `components`, `modules` and `services` in your app. For instance, if you remove the `AppComponent` from the `declarations: []` array; it no longer knows where to find that component and you will see error.

> declarations: []

This list the `Components` in your app. in the `AppModule` you should only include minimum required `components` for your app to start. From there you should build `level` folder structure. Each level can have a `Module` of their own.

> imports: []

This list all the modules used in your app. This includes the sub `levels` in your app.

> providers: []

This list all the services in your app.

> Here in a sample multilayer app could be like

```
src
|app.component.css
|app.component.html
|app.component.ts
|app.module.ts
   home
      |home.component.css
      |home.component.html
      |home.component.ts
      |home.module.ts
   user
      |user.component.css
      |user.component.html
      |user.component.ts
      |user.module.ts
   services
      |user.service.ts
```

> In this case your `app.module.ts` would look like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule,
    UserModule
  ],
  providers: [,
    UserService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So similar structure will be on `HomeModule` and `UserModule` file this their respective files and service.

As long as you import all the modules to the `AppModule` you do not need to declare a `Component` that has already been declared in a sub `Module`.